# How to solve $x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5=62$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

$$x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5=62$$

The roots in the set of Real numbers is $x=2$, but how solve it?

Comment: Why the quick downvote?

Comment: There is no general way to solve polynomial equations of degree $5$ or more.

Comment: @5xum That does not mean a specific one is unsolvable.

Comment: @SimpleArt Which is why I posted that as a comment, not as an answer...

Comment: @Ahmed: It factors as; $(x-2) \left(x^4+3 x^3+7 x^2+15 x+31\right)$. It has one real and four imaginary roots.The divisors of $62$ are $1, 2, 31, 62$, so that makes it easy to check. See [*Rational Root Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: We have
$$1+x+\cdots+x^5 = 63 = \dfrac{1-x^6}{1-x}$$ which implies
$x^6-63x+62=0$.
If $x=p/q$ (with coprime integers $p,q$) is a root, then the rational root theorem implies that $p$ divides $62$, $q$ divides $1$.
You should be able to conclude.

Comment: @SimpleArt he added one to both sides...

Comment: Why this downvote??

Comment: @Watson exactly what I was about to write. This reduction makes it much easier to see how many roots there are, and easier to factor. Sometimes increasing the order even simplifies things. I think you should write it as an aswer, it's most illuminating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem):

$$62\implies1,2,31,62$$

Thus, it is easy enough to check if $x=\pm1,\pm2,\pm31,\pm62$ are roots.  Indeed, if we check, we find that $x=2$ is the only rational root.  The remaining roots can be deduced to be complex since after factoring out, we find it has only one real relative minimum at $x=-1.55$ such that $\left(x^4+3 x^3+7 x^2+15 x+31\right)>0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I don't think these roots are correct..

Comment: It is worth adding that it is simple to check for a *rational* root but if none is found this does not mean there is no *real-valued* root. In this particular example, we are lucky.

Comment: @Euler_Salter You mean the $1,31,62$ cases?  That is why you check them.  Indeed, they are not, so we toss them aside.  But $2$ was a root (YAY!)

Comment: Oh sorry, misread!

Comment: @Florian Well, that's what the last sentence is supposed to be for.

Comment: @SimpleArt After finding $x=2$ , How you can deduct that other roots are complex ?

Comment: @S.H.W After you factor out $(x-2)$, you get a polynomial degree $4$.  I then took the derivative to get a polynomial degree $3$.  I then factored it over the reals (this is much easier than degree $4$) to deduce it had only one real root.  This meant the $4$th degree polynomial had only one relative minimum and plugging in $x=-1.55$, it is greater than $0$, so it will always be greater than $0$ for $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra you know it must have $5$ complex roots. Now from one of the comments you see that one is real and the other are complex. Mathematica gives:

[image: Roots]

Comment: This is not an answer, however in this way you can see the other roots, would have been to long to write in a comment!

Comment: Aw dang, that would've been real cool if I could click the "Step-by-step solution" button from here.  You ought to provide the link.

Comment: @SimpleArt If someone knows how to provide a link to Mathematica they should tell me. But if you are a student or a researcher, you should be able to get Mathematica for free and then you can either use Mathematica or Walfram Alpha to get the solutions!

Comment: Yeah, I usually use WolframAlpha.  :D

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+0%3Dx%5E4%2B3x%5E3%2B7x%5E2%2B15x%2B31

Comment: @SimpleArt, I couldn't do it on the programme, but using walfram alpha online that's all I can do http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%3D62 , however you need to go Proù